# Detecting click on empty part of the stage in easelJs

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I have a problem detecting mouse click / touch on empty part of the stage. This is my set up:

```
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
stage.addChild(exportRoot);
stage.addEventListener('click', onStageClicked);

function onStageClicked(event) {
  console.log('event.currentTarget: ', event.currentTarget);
  console.log('event.target: ', event.target);
  console.log('event.target.parent: ', event.target.parent);
};
```

I only get log in console when some shape or image that is on stage is clicked but not when actual empty part of stage is clicked. How do i detect click on empty part of the stage / canvas?

tnx

Luka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the 'stagemousedown' or 'stagemouseup' events. I pulled the code below from the 
EaselJS documentation here: http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/

```
stage.on("stagemousedown", function(evt) {
    alert("the canvas was clicked at "+evt.stageX+","+evt.stageY);
})
```

Comment: Tnx. It is a workaround that works. :)
This is relevant from docs and i have missed it:

_For the stage, just like every other display object, you will only get events when the mouse is over a non-transparent pixel._